# Android : Menu Item always overflows in portrait

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I am developing an Android application which uses [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) and
[ActionBarSherlock](http://www.actionbarsherlock.com/).

I want to include a MenuItem in a particular SherlockListFragment which
onClick would refresh the content. The issue I have is that the item always
overflows even though there is plenty of space. When the device is turned to
landscape orientation the item moves into the ActionBar automatically.

Can anyone help with this issue? I have set the showAsAction to "always" but
still the issue is not fixed.

This is the XML file for the menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:title="S"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    />
</menu>
```

This is the code in the SherlockListFragment

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater = getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_news,menu);
   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

This is what the application is currently looking like:

[image]

I need the button in the ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

try to set an icon

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_done_holo_light"
```

OR use flag withText

```
android:showAsAction="withText|always"
```

Comment: have you applied the SharlockActionBar Theme to the activity ?

Comment: In styles.xml
'<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" />'